# PHP. Issue with incrementor

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php

$html=<<<EOF  
    <p>{${$var[$n++]}[name]}</p>    
EOF;

$array=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);

for ($y = 0; $y < count($array) / 3; ++$y)
    { echo $html; }

?>
```

And for every loop `$n` is counted from the beginning: 0,1,2 → 0,1,2 → 0.

What should I do if I want continued `$n`: 0,1,2 → 3,4,5 → 6?

---

### Live example

```
<?php

$vps_de_ctt_s1=array(       
    "name"=> "Xen VPS 200",
    // etc      
);  

$vps_de_ctt_s2=array(       
    "name"=> "Xen VPS 400",
    // etc      
);  

// etc

$dc_id_tmp=array(
    "vps_de_ctt_s1",
    "vps_de_ctt_s2",
    "vps_de_ctt_s3",

    "vps_de_ctt_s4",
    "vps_de_ctt_s5",
    "vps_de_ctt_s6",

    "vps_de_ctt_s7"
);

$html=<<<EOF
<tr>
    <td class="column-left">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>{${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}[name]}</h5>
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>{${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}[name]}</h5>
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>{${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}[name]}</h5>
    </td>
</tr>
EOF;

?>

<?php for ($y = 0; $y < count($dc_id_tmp) / 3; ++$y)    
    { echo $html; }    
?>
```

---

Garbage text for word count. Can't update post without it. Garbage text for word count. Can't update post without it. Garbage text for word count. Can't update post without it. Garbage text for word count. Can't update post without it. Garbage text for word count. Can't update post without it.

Comment: What is the intention here? That is, why would you write such overly complex code?

Comment: im pretty sure we need to see more code, specially if you asking about a look on $n but we only see one small part about it

Comment: @Jason Every `$var` is a name of another array (called _var_ in this example). So I can create `<p>{${$var[$n++]}[name]}</p>`, `<p>{${$var2[$n++]}[name]}</p>` and get data from arrays _var_, _var2_, etc.

Comment: @Markedagain OK. I'm going to add more code.

Comment: The problem is that $html is only evaluated once, but you're trying to use it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this code.

```
<?php
function htmlcontent($i) {
//use global keywork to access ur local variables 
// [variable scope][1]
 global $dc_id_tmp,  $vps_de_ctt_s1, $vps_de_ctt_s2;

 echo '<tr>
    <td class="column-left">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>'.${$dc_id_tmp[$i]}['name'].'</h5>
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>'.${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}['name'].'</h5>
    </td>
    <td class="column-right">
        <h5>'.${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}['name'].'</h5>
    </td>
</tr>';
}
?>

<?php for ($y = 0; $y < count($dc_id_tmp_all) ; ++$y)    
    { htmlcontent($y); }    
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this way it returns `{${$dc_id_tmp[$i++]}[name]}` instead of data from array `$vps_de_ctt_s1` (Xen VPS 200).

Comment: Now the script mixes data in a strange way: 1,1,2 → 2,2,3 → 3,3,4.

Comment: In fact I started from scratch and recoded this page. It is not too automated now, but works fine. Thank you for attention.